# Finding details of the NSError webkit domain

Tags: iphone

I am unable to find the details of the NSError webkit domain, including the definition of the error codes in this domain.  A search in the iOS docs yields nothing, nor a search here on SO, or in the iOS forums. I think this ought to be in a header file, but I'm unsure how to find it. Where can I find this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the [WebKit Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Miscellaneous/WebKit_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003839)

The header file you are looking for is the cunningly named `WebKitErrors.h`

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate the response, if not the sarcasm.

Comment: Ah, a little ribbing never hurt anyone. I suspect you were looking for the errors to be defined under `NSError` somewhere; but at least now you know to look for the `*Errors.h` files in frameworks. If I really thought you hadn't bothered looking at all I would have been blunter. Thanks for accepting the answer, though.